# Gentoo can't install mysql

Tags: mysql, installation, gentoo

When I try to install MySQL on Gentoo

```
emerge mysql
```

I get these errors

```
... ...
Calculating dependencies... done!

>>> Verifying ebuild manifests
!!! A file is not listed in the Manifest: '/usr/portage/perl-core/Storable/Storable-2.20.ebuild'
!!! A file is not listed in the Manifest: '/usr/portage/virtual/perl-Storable/perl-Storable-2.20.ebuild'
... ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched on Google, and didn't find any answers.

Finally, I refreshed portage like this

```
rm -rf /usr/portage
emerge --sync
```

Now it works!

Comment: It looks like your portage is very old or it is corrupted.  Gentoo expects you to update the portage tree on a regular basis.  Or else you would not been getting the new software.